# Entity Framework - Any Way to Apply AntiXssEncoder.HTMLEncode() Before Insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am building an ASP.NET MVC web application that uses Entity Framework. User input is stored in a database and some of this is later displayed. In order to prevent cross-site scripting, I would to run all the user inputted data that is saved to the database through AntiXssEncoder.HTMLEncode() before it is inserted. I know I could manually run every field through the function; however, I am wondering if there is a more efficient way; for example, modifying the DBConext class to add this logic before it attempts to save data. Right now, I have something like this:

```
     [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ModuleOne(ModuleOneData formData)
    {

        ModuleOneViewModel vm = new ModuleOneViewModel();
        HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
        Int32 newHireID = Convert.ToInt32(ticket.Name);
        Employee newHire = dbContext.Employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.EmployeeID == newHireID);
        String sigFileName = "";
        // Pay Selection

        newHire.PaySelection = AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(formData.PaySelection, false);
        newHire.PaySelectionDate = formData.PaySelectionDate;
        newHire.PaySelectionSignature = formData.PaySelectionDate;
```

and so on for many more fields. 
Alternatively, is there any way to loop through the incoming POST data and apply this function? For reference, ModuleOneData looks like this:

```
  public class ModuleOneData
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    public String PaySelection { get; set; }
    public String PaySelectionSignature { get; set; }
    public String PaySelectionDate { get; set; }
    public String PaySelectionAccountType { get; set; }
    public String PaySelectionAccountNumber { get; set; }
    public String PaySelectionRoutingNumber { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase PaySelectionCheck { get; set; }
    public String DirectDepositInitials { get; set; }
    public String MoneyNetworkInitials { get; set; }

    public String WorkCompSignature { get; set; }
    public String WorkCompSignatureDate { get; set; }

    public String JobDescriptionSignature { get; set; }
    public String JobDescriptionSignatureDate { get; set; }

    public String MemoSignature { get; set; }
    public String MemoSignatureDate { get; set; }

    public String CriminalCheckSignature { get; set; }
    public String CriminalCheckDate { get; set; }

    public String AgeAcknowledgmentSig { get; set; }
    public String AgeAcknowledgmentSigDate { get; set; }

    public String DocumentReceiptSignature { get; set; }
    public String DocumentReceiptDate { get; set; }

    public String HandbookSignature { get; set; }
    public String HandbookSignatureDate { get; set; }

    public String DatingPolicySignature { get; set; }
    public String DatingPolicyDate { get; set; }

    public String UniformReceiptSignature { get; set; }
    public String UniformReceiptDate { get; set; }


   public string ageSigData { get; set; }
    public string paySigData { get; set; }
    public string workCompSigData { get; set; }
    public string jobSigData { get; set; }
    public string documentSigData { get; set; }
    public string handbookSigData { get; set; }
    public string uniformSigData { get; set; }
    public string criminalSigData { get; set; }
    public string harassmentSigData { get; set; }
    public string datingSigData { get; set; }

}
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the most "efficient" way is to manually map every single field. However, this is the largest manual intervention.

What you should not do is in any way modify the dbcontext to perform this operation since at that point you are coupling business logic/validation with data persistence.

If you are willing to take a bit of a performance hit you can always use reflection to loop through all public string properties and call HtmlEncode on each value:

```
var formData = new ModuleOneData();
    formData.PaySelection = "test1";
    formData.PaySelectionSignature = "test2";

    formData
        .GetType()
        .GetProperties().Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(string)).ToList()
        .ForEach(x => 
            x.SetValue(formData, AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(
                (string)x.GetValue(formData), false)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be encoding on output (when you display), not when storing.